# python pd.to_datetime still returning a string even though there are no errors

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have Timestamp column in my dataframe (df) with format 2019-01-01T00:00:00-05:00.  I am using the following code to convert it to datetime, yet it still returns a string.

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: On pyhton 3.10 seems to work. Does it work for you?
```pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01T00:00:00-05:00", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00-0500', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-300)')```

Comment: if you have mixed UTC offsets in your data, the data type will stay object. pandas cannot handle mixed UTC offsets with the built-in data type 'datetime64[ns]'. You can use `pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], utc=True)` - that will give you datetime64 data type but convert everything to UTC. You might want to extract the UTC offset before, so you keep that info.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, with Python 3.11.8. Sharing this for the benefit of others battling with it as well. If I figure out the answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: I promised to post the answer here if I figured it out.  Well, I haven't, quite, but I found a usable workaround.  Could be a bug in `pandas`.  I had to resort to assigning the relevant column of the dataframe to a temporary series, and then assign the dataframe column to that, like this: `temp_Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])`, and then `df['Timestamp'] = temp_Timestamp`.